# Row operations within a group of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I need to perform various operations between rows that belong to the same group, e.g. find the difference between them. For example, I have the following:

```
 var1  var2

  1      7
  1     10
  1     15
  2      3
  2      9
  2      5
```

and I want to get the following:

```
 var1  var2   var3

  1      7     NaN
  1     10      3
  1     15      5
  2      3     NaN
  2      9      6
  2      5     -4
```

I understand I can loop over the different groups of var1, get the difference using the shift operator, and then append the results. I wonder if there is a better way to do it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: With `groupby['var1']` you can work on each group independently, e.g. `df.groupby['var1'].diff()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `transform` on the `groupby` object to add a new column back to the original df:

```
In [58]:    
df['var3'] = df.groupby('var1')['var2'].transform(lambda x: x.diff())
df

Out[58]:
   var1  var2  var3
0     1     7   NaN
1     1    10   3.0
2     1    15   5.0
3     2     3   NaN
4     2     9   6.0
5     2     5  -4.0
```

So this groups on 'var1' and then calls a lambda on each group to calculate the difference and using `transform` will return a series with it's index aligned to the original df so you can add it back as a new column

Comment: Interesting, it seems to also work without the `transform`, just simply using `apply`.