# Calculation within Pandas dataframe group

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I've Pandas Dataframe as shown below. What I'm trying to do is, `partition (or groupby) by BlockID, LineID, WordID`, and then within each group use `current WordStartX - previous (WordStartX + WordWidth)` to derive another column, e.g., WordDistance to indicate the distance between this word and previous word.

This post [Row operations within a group of a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145468/row-operations-within-a-group-of-a-pandas-dataframe) is very helpful but in my case multiple columns involved (WordStartX and WordWidth).

```
 *BlockID  LineID  WordID  WordStartX  WordWidth     WordDistance
0        0       0       0         275        150                 0
1        0       0       1         431         96   431-(275+150)=6        
2        0       0       2         642         90   642-(431+96)=115
3        0       0       3         746        104   746-(642+90)=14
4        1       0       0         273         69         ...
5        1       0       1         352        151         ...
6        1       0       2         510         92
7        1       0       3         647         90
8        1       0       4         752        105**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `diff()` and `shift()` functions are usually helpful for calculation referring to previous or next rows:

```
df['WordDistance'] = (df.groupby(['BlockID', 'LineID'])
        .apply(lambda g: g['WordStartX'].diff() - g['WordWidth'].shift()).fillna(0).values)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Psidom for your quick response - your solution not only works but also concise and elegant!!