# calculation over each group of a multi index object pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate a value for each group of a groupby object but repeat it for each row of the group. 
[Calculation within Pandas dataframe group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40493829/calculation-within-pandas-dataframe-group) this does not work although the title seems to be what I need. 
I cannot see if there is something wrong with the formula. it is supposed to be a sort of sumproduct in excel vocabulary.

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({'Supplier': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B','B'], 'Id': ['1','2','3','4','5'], 'a': [2,2,2,2,2], 'AVG' :[5,6,7,8,3], 'BP': [3,4,5,6,3], 'Hc': [0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15]})

dat = dat.groupby(['Supplier', 'Id'])['a','AVG', 'BP','Hc'].sum()



for supplier in dat.index[0]:
    dat['s'] = np.sqrt((2 * (dat['a'])/ (
        ((dat['AVG'] * dat['BP'] * (dat['Hc']/4)).sum()))))
```

the result that I get is this:

```
             a  AVG  BP    Hc         s
Supplier Id                            
A        1   2    5   3  0.15  0.902358
         2   2    6   4  0.15  0.902358
         3   2    7   5  0.15  0.902358
B        4   2    8   6  0.15  0.902358
         5   2    3   3  0.15  0.902358
```

but I want to get something like:

```
             a  AVG  BP    Hc         s
Supplier Id                            
A        1   2    5   3  0.15  x
         2   2    6   4  0.15  x
         3   2    7   5  0.15  x
B        4   2    8   6  0.15  y
         5   2    3   3  0.15  y
```

x and y here are just here to show that the number should be different for each "group"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

`groupby.apply` function gives you access to each group(Supplier) dataframe.

```py
def cal_func(df):
    df['s'] = np.sqrt((2 * (df['a'])/ (
        ((df['AVG'] * df['BP'] * (df['Hc']/4)).sum()))))
    return df

dat_new = dat.groupby(['Supplier']).apply(cal_func)
dat_new

  Supplier Id  a  AVG  BP    Hc         s
0        A  1  2    5   3  0.15  1.200600
1        A  2  2    6   4  0.15  1.200600
2        A  3  2    7   5  0.15  1.200600
3        B  4  2    8   6  0.15  1.367971
4        B  5  2    3   3  0.15  1.367971
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dat = pd.DataFrame({'Supplier': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B','B'], 'Id': ['1','2','3','4','5'], 'a': [2,2,2,2,2], 'AVG' :[5,6,7,8,3], 'BP': [3,4,5,6,3], 'Hc': [0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15]})

dat = dat.groupby(['Supplier', 'Id'])['a','AVG', 'BP','Hc'].sum()


dat['s'] = np.sqrt((2 * (dat['a']))/(dat['AVG']* dat['BP']* (dat['Hc']/4)).groupby(level=0).sum())

print(dat)


             a  AVG  BP    Hc         s
Supplier Id                            
A        1   2    5   3  0.15  1.200600
         2   2    6   4  0.15  1.200600
         3   2    7   5  0.15  1.200600
B        4   2    8   6  0.15  1.367971
         5   2    3   3  0.15  1.367971
```